# getting sub array from the given array in php

Tags: php

I have a array variable **$data** which has the following array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rowdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (

                            [wiecont_03] => 
                            [tevrc_04] => 
                            [opmerkTXT] => Overall NPS
                            [0] => Array-----------------------
                                (                              |
                                    [0] => rapport             |
                                    [1] => npsorg              |
                                    [3] => npsdetbe            | i want this
                                                                  part of the array
                                )-------------------------------

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [DOELGROEP] => 2
                            [KANTOOR] => 2
                            [OBLIGOCATEGORIE] => 3
                            [NAAM] => dfdf
                            [WEIGHT] => 0.95
                            [opmerkTXT] => Overall NPS
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => npsorg
                                    [3] => npsdetbe
                                )

                        )

                )

            [reason] => column values are not correct
        )

)
```

from the above array structure i want to fetch the sub array if any as depicted by the dotted line.

**Desired Output:**

```
                                 [0] => Array
                                (                              
                                    [0] => rapport             
                                    [1] => npsorg              
                                    [3] => npsdetbe            
                                )
                                 and 

                                  [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => npsorg
                                    [3] => npsdetbe
                                )
```

**What i have tried:** i tried `array_slice()` and `array_chunks()` but none of them worked in my case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the large array follow a specific pattern?

Comment: @DainisAbols no it doesnot.that is the main problem.

Comment: Well, is it at least always in depth 3 ?

Comment: @DainisAbols no,only the structure will always remain the same

Comment: just functions won't tell us much, what is the concrete code that you tried (i.e. show how you accessed that array, which part you sliced/chunked/derefenced) and what you did to that part to get the final data out; what did that code give you, and why do you think it gave you that?

Comment: Can you show a simple diagram of the structure and add that to your question? I don't think that `$arr[0]['rowdata'][0][0]` or `$arr[0]['rowdata'][1][0]` will do the trick ...

Comment: It's the deepest array in the structure the one you want to get?

Comment: @Teknotica thanks for the response,i have marked the array i want ti fetch in my question,please have a look

Comment: We need to know more specific, how to know, what array in the structure you need. @Teknotica meant: Is the array you need **always** the deepest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can do it(in short) like this:

Demo: https://eval.in/86588

```
<?php 
$arr = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        "rowdata" => array
        (
            "0" => array
            (

                "wiecont_03" => "",
                "tevrc_04" => "",
                "opmerkTXT" => "Overall NPS",
                "0" => array
                (
                    "0" => "rapport",
                    "1" => "npsorg",
                    "3" => "npsdetbe"
                )

            ),

            "1" => array
            (
                "DOELGROEP" => 2,
                "KANTOOR" => 2,
                "OBLIGOCATEGORIE" => 3,
                "NAAM" => "dfdf",
                "WEIGHT" => 0.95,
                "opmerkTXT" => "Overall NPS",
                "0" => array
                (
                    "1" => "npsorg",
                    "3" => "npsdetbe",
                )

            )

        )


    )

);
$re = array();
//print_r($arr[0]['row_data']);
$i=0;
foreach($arr[$i]['rowdata'] as $a){
if(is_array($a[0])){
  array_push($re,$a[0]);
  }
          $i =$i+1;
}
print_r($re);
```

**TRY THIS:**
Demo : https://eval.in/86560

```
$arr = array
(
    "0" => array
    (
        "rowdata" => array
        (
            "0" => array
            (

                "wiecont_03" => "",
                "tevrc_04" => "",
                "opmerkTXT" => "Overall NPS",
                "0" => array
                (
                    "0" => "rapport",
                    "1" => "npsorg",
                    "3" => "npsdetbe"
                )

            ),

            "1" => array
            (
                "DOELGROEP" => 2,
                "KANTOOR" => 2,
                "OBLIGOCATEGORIE" => 3,
                "NAAM" => "dfdf",
                "WEIGHT" => 0.95,
                "opmerkTXT" => "Overall NPS",
                "0" => array
                (
                    "1" => "npsorg",
                    "3" => "npsdetbe",
                )

            )

        )


    )

);
$re = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
    foreach($a as $b){
       foreach($b as $c){
          array_push($re,$c[0]);
       }
    }
}
print_r($re);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => rapport
            [1] => npsorg
            [3] => npsdetbe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => npsorg
            [3] => npsdetbe
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks a lot.+1 will mark this as answer after few minutes if i wont get other better solution.thanks again.

Comment: awlad thanks again.need one more help.how to delete the last 2 elemnt from the above array?i tried unset ($data_failures[count($data_failures)-2]); but its not working

Comment: you want to delete from output array?

Comment: awlad: no.i want to delete from the original array i.e. $data in your case $arr

Comment: This array:   "0" => array
                (
                    "1" => "npsorg",
                    "3" => "npsdetbe",
                ) ?

Comment: no no this is the output array(the one you mentioned above) ,i want to delete the last two elements from the original array.

Comment: This one:   "WEIGHT" => 0.95,
                "opmerkTXT" => "Overall NPS",?

Comment: ya that array only.from that  want to delete the last two elements

Comment: unset ($arr[0]['rowdata'][count($arr[0]['rowdata'])-1]['NAAM']); unset ($arr[0]['rowdata'][count($arr[0]['rowdata'])-1]['WEIGHT']);

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is same in all case then this function is fine

```
function getMyArray($array){
  $rowdata = $array[0]['rowdata'];

  $resultArray = array(); 
  foreach($rowdata as $val){
    $resultArray[] = $val[0];
  }

  return $resultArray;
}
```

Usage:-

```
$array = "YOUR ARRAY HERE";
$result = getMyArray($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $value){
    print_r($value[0]);
}
```