# delete the last two elements from the multidimensional array having a sub array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the folowing multidimensional array from which i want to delete the last two elements from the sub array(there may be any number of subarray).

```
    $data=  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rowdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [DOELGROEP] => 2
                            [KANTOOR] => 2
                            [OBLIGOCATEGORIE] => 3
                            [] => Overall NPS
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => npsorg
                                    [3] => npsdetbe
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [DOELGROEP] => 2
                            [KANTOOR] => 2
                            [OBLIGOCATEGORIE] => 3
                            [] => Overall NPS
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => npsorg
                                    [3] => npsdetbe
                                )

                        )

                )

            [reason] => column values are not correct
        )

)
```

Desired Output:

```
$data=  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rowdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [DOELGROEP] => 2
                            [KANTOOR] => 2
                            [OBLIGOCATEGORIE] => 3

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [DOELGROEP] => 2
                            [KANTOOR] => 2
                            [OBLIGOCATEGORIE] => 3


                        )

                )

            [reason] => column values are not correct
        )

)
```

**what i have tried:**

```
unset ($data[count($data)-2]);
```

the above code is not working i.e. its not removing the last two elements.what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the answer from your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967644/getting-sub-array-from-the-given-array-in-php) question and add `unset` to that version?

Comment: @DainisAbols i tried that also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was not working `unset ($data[count($data)-2]);`  because `count($data)-2 = -1`  so your array $data doesn't have a key -1, $data[-1]. 
You need to follow your array example $data[0]['rowdata'][0]['ab'].

If you are sure that you will have always that array 'design' go with this.

```
   <?php
         $data = Array(
            0 => Array(
                'rowdata' => Array(
                    0 => Array
                        (
                            'DOELGROEP' => 2,
                            'KANTOOR' => 2,
                            'OBLIGOCATEGORIE' => 3,
                            0 => Array
                                (
                                    1 => 'npsorg',
                                    3 => 'npsdetbe'
                                )
                        ),
                    1 => Array
                        (
                            'DOELGROEP' => 2,
                            'KANTOOR' => 2,
                            'OBLIGOCATEGORIE' => 3,
                            0 => Array
                                (
                                    1 => 'npsorg',
                                    3 => 'npsdetbe'
                                )

                        )

                ),       
                    'reason' => 'column values are not correct'
                )
            );

 echo '<pre>';
echo '<h1>before</h1>';
        print_r($data);


    foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $k => $v){
       unset($data[0]['rowdata'][$k][0]);
    }

       echo '<h1>After</h1>';
        print_r($data);

         //unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0][0]);   
        // unset($data[0]['rowdata'][1][0]);
```

Update:
You can either,

```
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0][0]);
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][1][0]);
```

Or

```
 foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $k => $v){
   unset($data[0]['rowdata'][$k][0]);
}
```

Updated example: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VkPdZ7)

Comment: thanks jorge :) i was doing a silly mistake on my side thats why was not getting the required output.thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0]['ab'],$data[0]['rowdata'][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom filter function

```
function myFilter($val){
foreach($val as $key=>$val){
$len =  sizeof($val);   
  for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){ 
     $val[$i] = array_splice($val[$i],0,-2);
  }
    }
 return $val;
}
```

Then call  array_map

```
$data = array_map('myFilter',$data);
print_r($data);
exit();
```

You can see more info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: This only works for a single sub array. i will update my answer to your new requirement

Answer (score 1):

As you know you are removing elements from multidimensional array you have to reach up to that dimension. After that you need to have all keys of that array. You can use array_keys. You will get an array of keys. Then by using it you can unset last two elements of an array. You have to use this in loop.

You have to achieve:

```
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0]['ab']);
unset($data[0]['rowdata'][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use end function which will work for non-numerical indexes.
This should work I think :

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    end($data[0]['rowdata'][0]);
    unset(key($data[0]['rowdata'][0]));
    reset($data[0]['rowdata'][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mrcoder Same thing, except you should wrap this around a foreach function to parse all your "main" arrays.

```
$toDel = 2;
foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $main){
    for($i=0; $i<toDel; $i++){
        end($main);
        unset(key($main));
        reset($main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the three keys you always want to keep are DOELGROEP, KANTOOR and OBLIGOCATEGORIE - the following will work.

```
$keep_indexes = array('DOELGROEP', 'KANTOOR', 'OBLIGOCATEGORIE');

foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $key => $val) {
    if(!in_array($key, $keep_indexes)) { unset($data[0]['rowdata'][$key]; }
}
```

Edit, if it's not Key specific and it's just always the last 2 columns, try:

```
foreach($data[0]['rowdata'] as $key => $val) {
    $i = 1;
    $count = count($data[0]['rowdata'][$key]);
    foreach($data[0]['rowdata'][$key] as $key2 => $val2) {
        if($i >= ($count - 2)) { unset($data[0]['rowdata'][$key][$key2]); }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: no i cant make it key specific,i just want to remove last two key and their elemnet.